# Is there a module that changes "node" links to "alias" links?

Tags: path-aliases

I use global redirect, pathauto and redirect modules.

Everything is fine, except one situation:
I couldn't find the anwser, maybe it is very easy problem..
I can give links to nodes by using "link" "redirection" modules.
I creating new field with the type of Link.
When i select links from the lists, i can link to any node by using "fields".

But i want to give links to nodes in "body" of "node".
When i write

```
<a href="/node/12">click here</a>
```

In node content, the links is written with "node" word.
But i want to see this link in page with its alias, like this:

```
<a href="/content/aliasOfNode12">click here</a>
```

Is it possible?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Freelinking](https://www.drupal.org/project/freelinking) module allows you to add tokens in text fields

Just install. The syntax is `[[nid:5]]` if you want an aliased link to node/5

Comment: thank you. but giving node id's as parameter, creates links with the node numbers like "node/5" rather than using node aliases.

Comment: That module creates the title and the alias from that token. Sorry if I didn't explain that well.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I was searching for this feature for 2 months. That really will help me :)))

Answer (score 3):

Other than using a `process` to rewrite the URLs, I don't know how to fix this after the fact.

In the future, though, the [Linkit](http://drupal.org/project/linkit) module integrates with WYSIWYGs and use filters to add URLs, which then get properly updated to the alias.

Comment: FWIW, Linkit also creates a similar filter and token which ends up in the fields when you use it.